# Android: Using grid view to emulate a chess board

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to use a grid view to represent an 8x8 chess board. I want the columns to span across the whole screen and all the cells to be perfect squares. I've read some tutorials but they don't really cater to this situation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would probably be easier not using a Gridview. Try looking for some open source chess games to see how they handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) is what you're looking for. It wasn't added until ICS though, so you may want to look into the support added in the [v7 support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-gridlayout)

Blogpost describing `GridLayout`s uses here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

Comment: Yeah I was originally using gridlayout but you can't set an onitemclicklistener for it and that's what i really need

Comment: Can you just setOnClickListener() for each View you add to the grid?

Comment: Yeah but that means I can only refer to the cells as Type View and not Type ChessPiece. And I've tried casting, it doesnt let me

Comment: Since the board is finite (just 8x8), you could create a map between your ChessPieces and Views. setOnItemClickListener() should really only be necessary when you have an unknown number of Views